# Need a SQL Server query that gets sets of 3 rows based on a date given

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get 3 rows per set based on a date given (must be this date) but I want the rows to be based on this date as:

```
1 ( row where the date from the date column is the next date after given date )   
0 ( row where the date is the closest date prior to the date given )  
-1 ( prior to the date at 0 )
```

And add a column with the relative number.

** The dates for the same name and item will never repeat.

For example, a set of rows:

```
Row ID, Name, Item, Number, Date   
1       Andy, Item1, 12030, 2014-06-30  
2       Andy, Item1, 62030, 2014-03-31  
3       Andy, Item1, 30300, 2013-12-31  
4       Andy, Item1, 40030, 2013-10-31  
5       Andy, Item1, 50030, 2013-08-30
6       John, Item2, 50240, 2014-04-30
7       John, Item2, 41400, 2014-03-31
8       John, Item2, 40509, 2014-01-31
9       Andy, Item2, 24004, 2014-03-31
10      Andy, Item2, 20144, 2013-12-31   
11      Andy, Item2, 20450, 2013-09-30   
12      Andy, Item2, 25515, 2013-06-30
```

If I have 2014-03-15 as the date and search for 'Andy', I expect:

```
 Row ID, Item,   Date,        Relative Date
 2,      Item1,  2014-03-31,  1  
 3,      Item1,  2013-12-31,  0  
 4,      Item1,  2013-10-31,  -1
 9,      Item2,  2014-03-31,  1
10,      Item2,  2013-12-31,  0   
11,      Item2,  2013-09-30,  -1
```

This is what I'm using which I have no issues switching if necessary:

```
DATEDIFF( quarter, 2014-03-31, date ) 

date BETWEEN DATEADD( quarter, -1, '20140315' ) AND   
DATEADD( day, 1 ( DATEADD ( quarter, 2, '20140315' ) )
```

which returns:

```
 Row ID, Item,   Date,        Relative Date
 2,      Item1,  2014-06-30,  1  
 3,      Item1,  2014-03-31,  0  
 4,      Item1,  2013-12-31,  -1
 9,      Item2,  2014-03-31,  0
10,      Item2,  2013-12-31,  -1
```

Is there a better way of doing this without date math?  I don't think I can accomplish exactly what I want with date math because it's hard to capture the exact 3 rows I need.

Perhaps something with row_number()?

Comment: Please clarify your logic.  Provide sample data that covers all possible cases and the desired result. Identify your SQL *Flavor* (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc) since date functions are not a part of the standard SQL.

Comment: I made some changes.  I'm happy to change to a different function.  I just don't know how to accomplish it.

Comment: @AndyD: Make **all** the changes. Most particularly the RDBMS vendoar as date functions are **not** standard.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to.  I have SQL as the tag and have mentioned SQL Server in the topic and the body.  I also see the functions here...   

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Comment: One more time. State what your task is fully and succinctly. Do not leave anything of importance out. For example, why is *March 15* special?  Then provide a single set of sample data that covers all special cases, the desired result, and the explanation of how exactly this result was calculated.

Comment: @AndyD remember we don't know your use case. We have no idea what prior and next dates mean or what prior to 0 means. When you write your question imagine the person has not idea whatsoever about the data and functions. You need to explain it such a way that it can picked up by someone who has never touched your work *ever*. read this - http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: But I mentioned the date I'm using to search on, gave sample rows, showed the query code, gave what I expect as a return and mentioned what I got instead.  I'm not sure what else I can do to clarify?  I'll try to make it clearer what next and previous mean but I thought that's what I did with the sets?

Comment: And thanks Pret for fixing up the format.  I wasn't sure how

Comment: I've added more detail to the description of 1, 0, -1.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Nearly there. Can you also state what happens when there are multiple rows fulfil a rule? You care correct in thinking about sets. So try and imagine the widest possible set of data conditions that could exist and from there create the sample set. and finally one more  point. If you use just ISO dates then the sample will be much easier to read for those of us not in the US

Comment: Ok I've 1) Revised the date formats 2) added a row id column and referred to them in the outputs 3) Added this note - ** The dates for the same name and item (changed from test to item) will never repeat.

Comment: I realized that I also need to add the relative date column.  I can fuss around with the DATEADD to get what I want but I also need the relative numbers to match the row

Comment: Sorry to bang on but can you be more specific about the version of SQL Server? For example `ROWNUMBER()` would be handy for this but it only exists in certain versions.

Comment: Also, do you actually have the column `Row ID` in your dataset or is it just for illustration?

Comment: It's actually Sybase IQ.  I'm revising the detail now for it.  Rownumber() can be used yeah

Comment: Actually it is SQL Server.  Sorry, there is a mix servers I have access to and I thought I checked the properties of the right one.  I believe SQL 2012 but not 100% sure.  Rownumber does work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    RowID int
    , Name varchar(25)
    , Item varchar(25)
    , Number int
    , [Date] datetime
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES (1, 'Andy', 'Item1', 12030, '2014-06-30T00:00:00')  
, (2, 'Andy', 'Item1', 62030, '2014-03-31T00:00:00')  
, (3, 'Andy', 'Item1', 30300, '2013-12-31T00:00:00')  
, (4, 'Andy', 'Item1', 40030, '2013-10-31T00:00:00')  
, (5, 'Andy', 'Item1', 50030, '2013-08-30T00:00:00')  

DECLARE @Date datetime 
SET @Date = '2014-03-15T00:00:00'

CREATE TABLE #NameItem
(
    ID int identity(1,1)
    , Name varchar(25)
    , Item varchar(25)
)

CREATE TABLE #Results
(
    NIID int
    , RowID int
    , [Date] datetime
    , RelativeDate int
)

INSERT INTO #NameItem
(Name, Item)
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Item
FROM #TEMP a

INSERT INTO #Results
(NIID, RowID, [Date], RelativeDate)
SELECT a.ID, b.RowID, b.[Date], b.RelativeDate
FROM #NameItem a
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 z.RowID, z.[Date], 1 AS RelativeDate
                FROM #TEMP z
                WHERE z.Name = a.Name
                AND z.Item = a.Item
                AND [Date] > @Date
                ORDER BY [Date]
            ) b

INSERT INTO #Results
(NIID, RowID, [Date], RelativeDate)
SELECT a.ID, b.RowID, b.[Date], b.RelativeDate
FROM #NameItem a
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 z.RowID, z.[Date], 0 AS RelativeDate
                FROM #TEMP z
                WHERE z.Name = a.Name
                AND z.Item = a.Item
                AND [Date] < @Date
                ORDER BY [Date] DESC
            ) b

; with cte_0 as
(
    SELECT a.NIID, a.[Date]
    FROM #Results a
    WHERE a.RelativeDate = 0
)

INSERT INTO #Results
(NIID, RowID, [Date], RelativeDate)
SELECT b.ID, c.RowID, c.[Date], c.RelativeDate
FROM cte_0 a
INNER JOIN #NameItem b
    ON a.NIID = b.ID
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1 z.RowID, z.[Date], -1 AS RelativeDate
                FROM #TEMP z
                WHERE z.Name = b.Name
                AND z.Item = b.Item
                AND z.[Date] < a.[Date]
                ORDER BY [Date] DESC
            ) c


SELECT a.Name, a.Item, b.RowID, b.[Date], b.RelativeDate
FROM #NameItem a
INNER JOIN #Results b
    ON a.ID = b.NIID
ORDER BY a.ID, b.RelativeDate DESC 

DROP TABLE #NameItem
DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: Hi.  Thank you.  I clarified above some more - the query would return more than just three rows.  It should be three rows per name / item by the given date.  I think Top will look it to 3?

Comment: @Andy D Changed to suit your requirments

Comment: thanks!!  That's exactly what I want as an output.  Now I just have to integrate it into the larger query.

Comment: I know you set up temp tables to prove it out but is it necessary for the actual query?  Like can I get away with not creating any temp tables and just union the three?

Comment: The first 2 can have a union, but the third needs the cte to find the relativedate 0 to calculate relativedate -1